# How to call a class method in Python?

Tags: python

My code is showing `binary_search` not defined, I tried creating a variable for it, but it still won't work

```
class Queue:

    def __init__(self):
        print("Welcome to shirley, you can check on our menu and select what you want to do xx")

        self.queue = ["gym", "bar", "restaurant", "store", ]

    def binary_search(self, target, low, high):

        # self=self.queue
        while low <= high:

            # self.queue = ["gym","bar","restaurant", "store",]
            mid = low + ((high - low) // 2)

            if self.queue[mid] == target:
                return self.queue[mid], mid

            elif self.queue[mid] > target:
                high = mid - 1

            else:
                low = mid + 1
        return -1
        # the end minus 1 (meaning we've got nowhere else
        # to look for), work out the middle of the array
        # and see if the number is present.

        result = binary_search(self.queue, target, 0, len(self.queue) - 1)


        if result != -1:
            print("Element is present at index " + str(result))
        else:
            print("Not found")

    def program(self):

        print("enter your search item")
        target = input()
        binary_search(target, 0, len(self.queue)-1)


q = Queue()

q.program()
```

[image: 1]

Comment: `binary_search()` is a class method. You need to use `self.binary_search(...)`

Comment: hi, if i use the self.binary_search()... it wont execute the code

Comment: It will fix the error. You could have other problems in your algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `binary_search` is defined as a bound function, you'll need to add `self` before calling the function.

From

```
binary_search(target, 0, len(self.queue)-1)
```

to

```
self.binary_search(target, 0, len(self.queue)-1)
```

In your `binary_search` function, you called `return` before the program will ever reach the

```
        if result != -1:
            print("Element is present at index " + str(result))
        else:
            print("Not found")
```

part. Looks like what you're trying to do is define another function that takes in a number *(`result`)*,
and prints out `"Element is present at index " + str(result)` if `result` is not `-1`, else, print `"Not found."`

Observe:

```
class Queue:

    def __init__(self):
        print("Welcome to shirley, you can check on our menu and select what you want to do xx")
        self.queue = ["gym", "bar", "restaurant", "store", ]

    def binary_search(self, target, low, high):
        # self=self.queue
        while low <= high:
            # self.queue = ["gym","bar","restaurant", "store",]
            mid = low + ((high - low) // 2)
            if self.queue[mid] == target:
                return self.queue[mid], mid
            elif self.queue[mid] > target:
                high = mid - 1
            else:
                low = mid + 1
        return -1

    def display(self, number):
        # the end minus 1 (meaning we've got nowhere else
        # to look for), work out the middle of the array
        # and see if the number is present.
        result = number
        if result != -1:
            print("Element is present at index " + str(result))
        else:
            print("Not found")

    def program(self):
        print("enter your search item")
        target = input()
        self.display(self.binary_search(target, 0, len(self.queue)-1))

test = Queue()
test.program()
```

Input:

```
Welcome to shirley, you can check on our menu and select what you want to do xx
enter your search item
bar
```

Output:

```
Element is present at index ('bar', 1)
```